# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prop' of undefined when using Bootstrap Multiselect

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using Bootstrap Multiselect by David Stutz. When I don't initialise the multiselect in my JS, it shows a div with all the options, no error there. But when I use the `multiselect()` method, it gives

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannnot read property of 'prop'...

I have checked all my included script and CSS files. I also followed some of the questions asked. The most popular solution was to check if I am including the same JS file twice. But I'm not.

I also tried including multiple versions of jquery and changed the CDN for `multiselect`, but that didn't work as well.

Here's the list of scripts

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.19.4/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.15/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css">
```

Also, the select list is getting generated via PHP and then I am appending the list of options into the select tag using jquery.

Here is the code snippet

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <select name="tags" class="form-control que-tags multiselect" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="select">Select</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['contextid']) && !empty($_POST['contextid'])) {

    $sel_tags = "SELECT DISTINCT tagid FROM mdl_tag_instance WHERE contextid=".$_POST['contextid'];
    $get_tags = mysqli_query($con, $sel_tags);
    $tag_num = mysqli_num_rows($get_tags);

    if($tag_num>0) {
        while($row_tag = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_tags)) {
            $tags[] = $row_tag['tagid'];
        }
        $all_tag_ids = join("','",$tags);

        $sel_tag_names = "SELECT * FROM mdl_tag WHERE id IN ('".$all_tag_ids."')";
        $get_tag_names = mysqli_query($con, $sel_tag_names);
        $num_tagnames = mysqli_num_rows($get_tag_names);

        if($num_tagnames>0){
            while($row_tagnames = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_tag_names)){
                echo "<option value=".$row_tagnames['id'].">".$row_tagnames['rawname']."</option>";
            }
        }
    }
    // echo $all_tag_ids;
    else {
        echo "<option value=\"invalid\">Invalid Option</option>";
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajaxData.php",
    data: "contextid="+contextid,

    success: function(data) {
        $('.que-tags').html(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
        alert(data.statusText);
    }
});

//Multiselect initialisation
$('.multiselect').multiselect();
```

Comment: Same problem here, and while stepping in the debugger I see a problem with `var $option = this.getOptionByValue(value);` (code inside bootstrap.multiselect) unexpectedly returning `undefined`.

Comment: It turns out this is not a duplicate, as the other question is not specific to multiselect. It turns out in my case, this was an issue of '\r' (non-printable character) being present in option values.